# Cytoscape String is giving me no result for network analysis on protein query at all

Tags: string, cytoscape

I'm using stringApp (v2.0.2) with Cytoscape (Version: 3.10.1).
When put in the gene name (ex, FOS, KDR, ...) using 'STRING:protein query', a message box says 'Your query returned no results.'.

A network diagram was usually occurred, and I could get data what I want until December 2023.

Comment: I just put "FOS, KDR" into STRING: protein query and it worked. So maybe it was a temporary network issue or a firewall issue?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is now working today. Maybe temporary server error. I needed to send these data by yesterday, so I was in a too much worried. Thanks!